# RegEx to accept String, # and a number

Tags: python, regex, regression, qregularexpression

I am trying to add the commit message hook to accept the following inputs in Gitlab:

```
bug 12345
bug #12345
BUG # 12345
Bug#12345
bug12345
```

The number 12345 should be changed to anything which is either a 5 digit or 6 digit number (not less than that, not greater than that)

It should get started from Bug, BUG or bug.

It should not have any other character than #  or space or blank that too just between the numbers and string "Bug/bug/BUG"

I need help with this ASAP.

I have tried to achieve this by :

```
^(BUG|bug|Bug)\ |#\d+
```

but this is not giving the desired output. I am taking reference from :

1. https://regex101.com/
2. https://github.com/google/re2/wiki/Syntax

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
^(BUG|bug|Bug) *(?:# *)?\d{5,6}$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/NUGpcq/1)

If you just want to match `bug` in a case insensitive way, you can write it as `(?i)^Bug *(?:# *)?\d{5,6}$`.

To match any whitespace, replace the literal spaces in the pattern with a `\s` construct.

*More details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `(BUG|bug|Bug)` - `BUG`, `bug`, or `Bug`
- `*(?:# *)?` - zero or more spaces followed with an optional sequence of a `#` followed with zero or more spaces
- `\d{5,6}` - five or six digits
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: You have some God Level powers @Wiktor
Worked like a charm!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: Hey @Wiktor what REGEX should be if I want to accept an optional string after space in the end? 

Like
It should accept : 
1. bug12345
2. bug12345 updated file1   (If a message is passed it should have a space compulsory)

Comment: @SameerAtharkar I think you mean `^(BUG|bug|Bug) *(?:# *)?\d{5,6}(?: .*)?$`

Comment: It should not have a number later..
It should only accept alphabets or sentences but not any number.

Like 
-> bug 12345 updated file one 

Sorry I wrote 1 previously

Comment: @SameerAtharkar `\D` matches any char but a digit. Use `^(BUG|bug|Bug) *(?:# *)?\d{5,6}(?: \D+)?$` then. Or, if there must be a single space between the bug and the text, and to support any whitespace - ``^(BUG|bug|Bug)\s*(?:#\s*)?\d{5,6}(?:\s[^\d\s]\D*)?$``.

Comment: It should not accept something like :

bug abcdef
bug 123456abcded
bug 12345#abcdef

but it should accept :

bug 12345 abcdef
bug#12345 abcdef

Comment: @SameerAtharkar `^(BUG|bug|Bug) *(?:# *)?\d{5,6}(?: \D+)?$` works, see [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/NUGpcq/2).

Comment: Worked like a charm....
I would really like to know how you became such a pro @Wiktor..

One more thing, Is there any way if someone tries to write or mention another bug then it should be able to display another number?

like
it should accept: 

`-> bug 12345 bug 21235 optional msg
-> bug 12345 bug#12345 `

Comment: @SameerAtharkar If I get it right, you want to validate and extract a portion of text. You will need PyPi regex module and a solution [like this](https://tio.run/##JYyxDoIwFEV3vuJFh/YhIQHEgahNiImrixsLIpQmFJrSJhrx27GN282951z1Nv00ZusqpJq0Ad3y9hXMcAJNHpZDkmb7HHxKXcxhUkZMYz2AnDkJpOe8EXd2GGRtmp5qQikryvt1cdZSWo4QumILITLKbkfdznYw5@r5yaPDF9FtQFmC6CmoLjtkJIIZA9GBLAIApcVoqIybWhnrbLr5X2wQ1/UH) (`regex.fullmatch(r'((?:BUG|bug|Bug) *(?:# *)?(?P<result>\d{5,6}))(?: (?1))*(?: \D+)?', s).captures("result")`).

Comment: @SameerAtharkar [This is how I became proficient in regex](https://www.buymeacoffee.com/wstribizew/my-regex-road-so-far).

Comment: That is really nice. 
How can we make that regex to accept this too @Wiktor? 
-> https://regex101.com/r/qqbN8v/1

I want it to accept now any value which is starting from 1 to any value which is 6 digit number. 

so basically I want it to accept anything between 1 to 999999 

and it should also accept the character which is ':' 
Like bug:12345 , bug : 12345 just like it is done for the #

Comment: Please consider this link: https://regex101.com/r/xtiRBW/1
The previous link was just the playground for me

Comment: I was able to use that ':' here : ^(BUG|bug|Bug) *(?:#* *)?(:)?( )?\d{5,6}(?: \D+)?$

but not sure how to make it 1 to 6 digit letter but it should not be 0 
It should be a valid number from 1 to 99999 and not 0 in the beginning.

https://regex101.com/r/Wmyyzc/1

Comment: @SameerAtharkar Maybe `^(BUG|bug|Bug) *(?:#* *)?(:)?( )?[1-9]\d{0,5}(?: \D+)?$` [will do](https://regex101.com/r/Wmyyzc/2).

Comment: Thanks a lot @Wiktor 
You are really a life saver..
I am wondering how can we make it accept bug 00001 or bug 01 ?
The number should be just a non zero.?
What will be the case now?

Comment: @SameerAtharkar You are changing requirements too fast. Use `^(BUG|bug|Bug) *(?:#* *)?(:)?( )?(?!0+(?![^ ]))\d{0,6}(?: \D+)?$`

Comment: Yes actually  we are trying to enhance it. :)
All credits goes to you buddy. 
Can you tell me how can we make it accept something: `bug123 test file2 updated` 
It should accept a number after the string or between the string but it should not start with a number. 

example :1.  bug12345 updated file 1 2. bug # 123 test1

Comment: @SameerAtharkar Try `^(BUG|bug|Bug) *(?:[#:] *)?(?!0+(?![^ ]))\d{0,6}(?: [^\s\d]\S*)*$`, see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/Wmyyzc/4).

Comment: Can you tell me how I can accept an optional ":" or "::" when there is a space just before the optional message?

Like 
`bug 12345::testmessage1` or `bug#123:testmessage1` and it also should accept `bug123 :: test message`
Can you please explain as well your answer? I tried to add (::)? but it was not letting me do the needfuls. 
https://regex101.com/r/Dfpk4o/1 Check here. 
Thanks a lot....

Comment: @SameerAtharkar Trying to guess: `^(BUG|bug|Bug) *(?:[#:] *)?[1-9]\d{0,5}(?:(?:[ :]|::).+)?$`? See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/Dfpk4o/2).

Comment: Thanks a lot. This was helpful. I even edited it and made it accept a spacebar in the beginning by making it https://regex101.com/r/hbsmjw/1 like this 
I am wondering, if there is any possibility that...we can make it in an complete OR condition and accept either this kind of string or else just one "Message one two" like either the string should accept whatever rule we have written or else one complete message like "Message one two" and nothing else.  Can we add this kind of condition ?
Is it possible via regex?

Comment: @SameerAtharkar Maybe you mean https://regex101.com/r/hbsmjw/2.